# vue.js v-for not rendering component laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am trying to build user messaging into my site. All of the data is passing through, but for some reason I can't get it to render right on the browser. If i delete the replies if section, the first message will render. The error message in the console is

Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

```
<template>
    <div v-if="message">

        <ul class="list-inline" v-if="message.users.data.length">
            <li><strong>In conversation</strong></li>
            <li v-for="user in message.users.data">{{ user.first_name }}</li>
        </ul>


        <div class="media" v-for="reply in message.replies.data">
            <div class="media-left">
                <img v-bind:src="reply.user.data.avatar" v-bind:alt="reply.user.data.name + ' avatar'">
            </div>

            <div class="media-body">
                <p>{{ reply.user.data.name }} &bull; {{ reply.created_at_human }}</p>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ reply.body }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <img v-bind:src="message.user.data.avatar" v-bind:alt="message.user.data.name + ' avatar'">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <p>{{ message.user.data.name }} &bull; {{ message.created_at_human }}</p>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ message.body }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        computed: mapGetters({
            message: 'currentMessage',
        }),
    }
</script>
```

///

```
         message:Object 
    body:"Message two" 
    created_at_human:"1 day ago" 
    id:3 last_reply_human:"1 day ago" 
    parent_id:null replies:Object 
    data:

    Array[2] 
    0:Object 
    body:"Another reply" 
    created_at_human:"1 day ago" 
    id:5 last_reply_human:null 
    parent_id:3 

    1:Object 
    body:"Reply to message two" 
    created_at_human:"1 day ago" 
    id:4 last_reply_human:null 
    parent_id:3 user:Object 

    data:Object avatar:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/44a0d18d423d13e1ce8ea37a6e7bb728?s=45&d=mm" 
    id:12 name:"James" 
    users:Object data:

Array[2] 

0:Object avatar:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/44a0d18d423d13e1ce8ea37a6e7bb728?s=25&d=mm" 
    id:12 
    name:"James" 

    1:Object avatar:"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0b6703d371c28c3c5baef0d80f49a5ea?s=25&d=mm" 
    id:7 
    name:"Dustin"
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point, `message.replies` is undefined. That means when you try to access the `data` property of `replies` you are throwing the observed error.

You can prevent this with a guard.

```
<template v-if="message.replies" >
  <div class="media" v-for="reply in message.replies.data">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

The `v-if` prevents the section from trying to render if there are no replies.

You also may need to handle

```
<div class="media-left" v-if="reply.user && reply.user.data">
  <img v-bind:src="reply.user.data.avatar" v-bind:alt="reply.user.data.name + ' avatar'">
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="media-body" v=if="reply.user && reply.user.data">
  <p>{{ reply.user.data.name }} &bull; {{ reply.created_at_human }}</p>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        {{ reply.body }}
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Essentially, anytime you have a long dot chain (`something.something.something`), you will need to take care to handle cases where the middle `something` may be undefined.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but I get the same error, and still no rendering. I am expecting replies.

Comment: @DustinSeaward Then you are likely missing a `user` on a `reply` in some of your data. You use `reply.user.data.avatar` and `reply.user.data.name`. If `reply.user` is ever undefined, you will also get the error.

Comment: I am not missing any data, it is all manually entered in, and double checked, but I think you are on the right track. If I remove just the statements with reply.user.data I render out the reply.body.

Comment: @DustinSeaward Post the full `message` object you're trying to render.

Comment: It's up in the question.

Comment: @Dustin So, if I'm reading that right, `message.replies.data` is an array with two objects, the first of which, doesn't have a user property.

Comment: I found the error, it was in the MessageController ----

return fractal()
            ->item($message)
            ->parseIncludes(['user', 'users', 'replies', 'replies.user'])
            ->transformWith(new MessageTransformer)
            ->toArray();
    }
-----
I had replies_user instead.... it works now. Thank you for helping narrow down the issue.